# problem with disc size

Tags: disk-usage

So I typed df -h in terminal and that's what I've got

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size Used   Free %Used Mounted on
/dev/sda6       669G  618G   18G  98% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           787M  1,2M  785M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,9G  216K  3,9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2       245G  235G  9,6G  97% /media/win7/4C109527109518D2
```

The values for /dev/sda6 doesn't match-it's about 51G difference. Where did it go? How can I fix it?

After typing du -sh I've got

```
du -sh
612G
```

of disk usage

And in gparted it shows me the correct size of disk free space(about 33G)

Comment: Which out of four values doesn't match?

Comment: Size of the filesystem should be equal to Free+Used Space. Size of the filesystem is correct. Based on the results of df -h and du -sh which values are simmilar I assume that there is the problem with Free Space value(should be 33G more)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the free space is reserved blocks, 5% of the total size by default, which in your case, makes about 33GB. That's probably much more then necessary, so you might want to reduce it to 1%, and to do that, run:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda6
```

The df -h command should show about 43GB free for /dev/sda6

Comment: It worked. Now it shows:

'/dev/sda6       669G  618G   45G  94% /'

Thanks!